# Can a Java Generic Using a Bound Parameter be Instantiated with its Upper Bound?

Tags: java, generics

For example:

```
class MyClass<T extends MyClass2> {
    // Do stuff...
}
```

Then later:

```
MyClass<MyClass2> myClass = new MyClass<MyClass2>();
```

Does this work?  My coworker's hunch is no, but I can't find anything to confirm that for me and the documentation suggests perhaps.

Comment: Just tested for myself - this exact code works.  (Didn't take nearly as long to test I was afraid it would.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong. Even `MyClass<MyClass> m = new MyClass<MyClass>();` should be valid expression (even useful, maybe).

Comment: does myclass extend myclass2?

Comment: Actually no, MyClass doesn't extend MyClass2, T extends MyClass2, it's a bound parameter.

Answer (score 4):

This works fine. I just wrote this:

```
public class MoreGeneric {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MyClass1<MyClass2>();
   }


  public static class MyClass1<T extends MyClass2>{}
  public static class MyClass2{}
}
```

And it compiled fine.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, that works just fine. Lower bounds are inclusive.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. `T extends ClassX` checks that `ClassX.isAssignableFrom(T.class))`.

super is the opossite, so you can use the bound class too.

And... you could program a test to find out :)

Comment: Did just that after I posted the question.  ;)